# Click function making page scroll in odd way (not to top of page)

Tags: javascript, jquery

First time asker, long time lurker.

I'm doing a fadein/out toggle that displays 1 of 2 charts depending on which button you click.

That bit works just fine, but I'm getting a weird page-jump glitch. Now, it's not the usual jump-to-the-top behaviour. I have that part covered in the code, and it doesn't do that.

Every time I click on one of the toggles, the page scrolls downward to the point where the chart area is at the bottom of the window.

But it gets weirder. If I make the browser window very short or very narrow (it's a responsive site), it stops doing this glitch. It's also not happening on iPhone or iPad at all, even though if I set the browser width to the same width as it would be on an iPad, the desktop browser still does the jumping.

There are no elements that are added/removed based on the viewport width in the area that's jumping around, and there are no anchor IDs that would be accidentally used as jump points.

Unfortunately I can't show the actual page to you, but I can show the script and a bit of the HTML.
The code for both toggles is the same, just with the IDs switched around.

The script:

```
    $('#left-toggle > a').click(function(c)
    {
        c.preventDefault();
        c.stopPropagation();
        $('#right-toggle').removeClass('toggle-active');
        $('#left-toggle').addClass('toggle-active');
        $(pricing_subscriptionID).fadeOut('fast', function(){
            $(pricing_singleID).fadeIn('fast', function(){

            });
        });
    });
```

The HTML for the toggles:

```
<div id="chart-toggle">
     <div id="left-toggle" class="toggle-active"><a href="#">Single Pricing</a></div>
    <div id="right-toggle"><a href="#">Subscription Pricing</a></div>
</div>
```

"toggle-active" is just for styling.

Any ideas?

It seems to be almost wanting to centre the toggles on the page, but it's not quite putting them in the middle either.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TmrLw/

Comment: Update: If I hide the charts with HTML comment tags, the page jumping doesn't happen anymore. Hmm.... Also, the height of the 2 charts is not the same. One is taller, so it expands the containing element. But I've never see that trigger a page jump before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of your link to `#`.  Here are some ways you can fix this:

#### 1. Replace "#" with something else

Instead of

```
<a href="#">Subscription Pricing</a>
```

Try this:

```
<a href="Javascript: void(0);">Subscription Pricing</a>
```

This will give you the cursor pointer you're looking for and avoid the page jump.

#### 2. Create a class with the pointer effect

If you use this CSS rule:

```
.pointer {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Then you can wrap your text with this class instead:

```
<div class="pointer">Subscription Pricing</div>
```

#### 3. Remove the default effect of "#"

This Javascript will get rid of its default effect:

```
$('a[href="#"]').click(function(e)
{
    // Cancel the default action
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply :) I actually tried this (should have mentioned it) by having the toggle DIVs handle the click, and removed the <a> entirely. It's still doing the jump. Keep in mind, it's not jumping to the top of the page and it doesn't do it depending on certain browser window widths... :S Let me see if I can duplicate the page and remove the sensitive info from it so you can see what I mean.

Comment: Here's the page. Scroll down and try clicking the chart toggles at different scroll positions, and window sizes :) http://heronymo.com/jump/ (i'll try adding in the jsfiddle too)

Comment: A fiddle would be better so I can make changes.

Comment: I tried a bunch of things and I have no idea why this is happening.  There might be a workaround though.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks very much for your help Michael. Great solution too, wouldn't have thought of that. Cheers!

Comment: It's actually a terrible solution but the only thing I could come up with.  I'd advise removing each line of `window.scrollTo` one at a time until you figure out where exactly it needs to be fired, and only fire it there.  I'm glad it works for you, though.

Comment: Haha I see (I still have a lot to learn about jQuery) Okay I'll do that and find out where the problem is. Hopefully I can come up with a proper solution in time, but this will do for now. The site has to go up soon. Thanks again for your time, Michael.

Answer (score 0):

Probably its because the link's href is # which links to the top of the document.
try to remove the href attribute

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't fix it :\ Thanks for the reply.